# Who needs octal representation?

Tags: c++, c, octal, representation

From my understanding octal digits in a number map to 3 bit segments, and will never truly represent a binary string of `2^n` length.

Out of curiosity, When/Why/How is this useful? :-)

..If the base of the primary representation of a word in an architecture is a **prime**(!) power of 2, *at least* make sure It's **even** ;-).

Comment: I think it's more about history than it is about current usefulness. I've used at least one computer a long time ago (something called an Alpha Micro) that actually dealt in octal values.

Comment: Basically if you don't want letters in your numbers.  Octal commonly requires additional 0's to be implicitly added to the left, but that doesn't usually change the value.

Comment: If you have a 6-bit computer...

Comment: @Rob If you have a 36 bit computer.  (They were very common once upon a time.)

Comment: Octal notation provides a handy shorthand for file permissions, which are grouped in 3's (read, write, execute) on Unix-ish systems.

Comment: It is not useful, it is a virus.  Which escaped from Maynard MA in the early 1970s, home of the Digital Equipment Corporation (aka DEC).  All of their documentation and tooling used octal notation.  Which in turn infected C and Unix, PDP-11 was the principal carrier.  Which infected many subsequent languages since their compilers and runtime libraries were often first implemented in C.

Comment: Octal is a *very* useful notation in the documentation of several assembler opcodes -- from memory, 80x86, Z80, MC68K. (ARM RISC CPU's have more registers, operators, and flags and so its assembly is based on nibbles instead.)

Comment: @HansPassant Hah. I agree about the virus part, but fortunately it seems It's far enough from evolving properly, and back to source codes.. ;-)

Comment: 'chmod 777' - about the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Shorter to type `'\0'` (an octal escape sequence) than `'\x0'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Octal can represent exactly a binary string of any length.
Although it's true that with 8 bit bytes and byte addressing,
hexadecimal seems more natural.  Historically, however...

- a lot of machines had 36 bit words, where octal made a lot of
  sense, and
- on the PDP-11 (on which the first C compilers ran), the
  machine instructions were divided into 3 bit groups: the high
  bit to flag whether the operation was on bytes or words, then
  a 3 bit op-code, and two six bit addresses, with the first
  3 bits the addressing mode and the second 3 the register
  involved.

At the time when C was first being invented, octal was probably
more frequently used than hexadecimal, and so the authors of the
language provided for it.  (I can't recall seeing it actually
used in recent code for a very long time, however.)

Comment: I think technically every time you see a literal 0 in code you're looking at octal :)

Comment: @NigelHarper Formally.  In practice, for values between 0 and 7, there is no difference between octal and decimal.

Answer (score 1):

At the times of Unix development there were machines (DEC) with 36-bit word. A 36-bit word is made of four 9-bits bytes, each of them represented by three octal digits.

Comment: IBM also, and indeed principally, by market share. As a matter of fact the 18 digit COBOL rule comes from 36-bit IBM hardware and BCD.